# Why does my SwiftUI Grid with Texts in a widget not render in monospaced like normal?

Tags: ios, swiftui, fonts, grid

An attempt at a simple question.

Why does this iOS widget view need `.monospaced().monospaced()` instead of simply `.monospaced()` to render in a monospaced font?

Same for `monospacedDigit()`.

I cannot reproduce this behavior in an app, only in a widget.

The workaround is simple and not even a big problem for my code. Still, it bothers me that I cannot find a way without this workaround.

Is this a bug?

Code:

```
struct widget_iosEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family
    
    var body: some View {
        let grid = [["a","i"],["1", "0"]]

        switch family {
        case .accessoryCircular:
            Grid {
                ForEach(grid, id: \.self) { rowWithCells in
                    GridRow {
                        ForEach(rowWithCells, id: \.self) { cell in
                            Text(cell)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.monospaced().monospaced()
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
```